# Magento 2: Missing entity types in CSV import

Tags: magento2, import, csv, importexport

I have a fresh instance of Magento 2.2. In the Import tab, there are only "Products" entity types. Should I enable anywhere rest? Like e.g "advanced pricing"? [image]

Edit. SOLVED -> Module "Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport" was disabled in Magento options